# Run multiple SSH commands in the same SSH session, fail/exit on first error

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a step in my Jenkins file, like this:

```
withCredentials([
    file(credentialsId: 'mysrv-key', variable: 'keyfile'),
    string(credentialsId: 'mysrv-host', variable: 'srvhost')
]) {
    sh '''ssh -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ${keyfile} 
root@${srvhost} /bin/bash << EOF
  echo "0"
  grep "inexisting-text" /path/to/somefile
  echo "1"
EOF'''
}
```

This experiment is to see if `grep` returning 1 would fail the `sh` step, but doesn't seem to. "1" is also printed in the output.

**Is it possible to run several commands through SSH, but without having to run multiple `ssh` commands, so that we don't have to open a new shell session for every single of them?**

Something equivalent to running `sh`, but all wrapped in an SSH session. Similar to how we do `withCredentials`, and run stuff under that block.

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious what are you asking. Your question (highlighted in bold in your post) is:

> Is it possible to run several commands through SSH, but without having
> to run multiple ssh commands, so that we don't have to open a new
> shell session for every single of them?

but before that question you demonstrate that you already run several commands (`grep` and `echo`) in a single SSH session

If your goal is to prevent further commands if `grep` command fails then you have to add `set -o errexit` (or `set -e`) to your EOF block.